# JS compare two objects. Return key of changed value(s)

Tags: javascript, object, compare

I am trying to compare two objects and return the key of the changed value.

```
 const a = {
    email: 'john@doe.nl',
    first_name: 'john',
    last_name: 'doe',
 };

 const b = {
    email: 'peter@doe.nl',
    first_name: 'peter',
    last_name: 'doe',
 };
```

Right now i have:

```
 Object.entries(user).reduce((key, val) => {
   // Got the key and val
   // Compare the second object against the key/val?
 });
```

Expected:
this changed: email & first_name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using a `filter`:

`Object.keys(a).filter( key => a[key] !== b[key] )`

This assumes that `a` and `b` have the same keys. Any new keys that are in `a` will show up as changed.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over one of the object and check if the key in second object have same value

```js
const a = {
  email: 'john@doe.nl',
  first_name: 'john',
  last_name: 'doe',
};

const b = {
  email: 'peter@doe.nl',
  first_name: 'peter',
  last_name: 'doe',
};

for (let keys in a) {
  if (b[keys] && a[keys] !== b[keys]) {
    console.log(keys)
  }

}
```